# Loss of internet connectivity caused by LAN (?)

Tags: networking, ip

Small office network with two servers, one configured for DHCP and DNS and a second one as SQL server, Veeam backup and some more functionality. We are having 4 to 5 times during the day (every day) loses of Internet connectivity, i.e. the router loses signal and restarts itself. Needless to say that it's affecting productivity. That all started happening since we moved in to the ISP’s new fiber network.

From the ISP side, the technician who’s visited us told us that it could be an internal network problem, specifically he claimed it might be happening because we changed the default router's IP to an new one that falls into our DHCP IP scope.

Could that be the case? Could it be a problem cause by our network?

edit: the router's DHCP has being disabled. A VM on Esxi 5.0, runninng Windows Server 2012 has being configured to act as the DHCP and DNS on the network.

Comment: Is the router also the DHCP server?  What's in its logs around the time it resets?

Comment: How's the connection to the router?   Wired or wireless?

Comment: If the router is loosing signal and resetting itself (and by resetting I assume you mean rebooting)  its a crappy and/or faulty router. Your routers DHCP server might cause issues for other clients (and it sounds to be badly set up), but it should not cause a router reset.

Comment: @stark no, a virtual machine on Vmware Esxi 5.0 running windows server 2012 acts as the DHCP server. The router's default IP has changed, so to fall in to the Network's IP scope defined by to the DHCP server.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille all wired

Comment: @stark 
Apr 1 04:01:41 dial: CCPE: Connection disabled. Exiting
Apr 1 04:03:33 dial: VDSL_IPTV: Dialing vdsl/eth_br ...
Apr 1 04:03:33 dial: VDSL_PPPoE: Dialing vdsl/eth_pppoe ...
Apr 1 04:03:34 dial: ADSL_IPTV: Dialing adsl/rfc1483 ...
Apr 1 04:03:34 dial: VDSL_PPPoE: Bringing up wan_vdsl0.835
Apr 1 04:03:34 dial: VDSL_IPTV: redundancy - Created list of backup connections.
Apr 1 04:03:34 dial: VDSL_IPTV: Bringing up wan_vdsl0.836
...

Comment: If it isn't a bad line, perhaps you did change another setting whilst changing the IP address.   What is IPTV doing in an office network?

Comment: Can you match the time of the resets in the logs to anything on the DHCP server?  If not, the IP issue is unlikely to be the problem.